# Find the volume of the region bounded by $z=x^3 + y^2 $, $z=0$, $-a<x<a$, and $-a<y<a$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, volume

Since $z \geq 0$ then,

$x^3+y^2 \geq 0 \rightarrow  x \geq -y^{2/3}$

So, I set up the integral as follows:

$$V = \int_{-a}^{a} \int_{-y^{2/3}}^{a} (x^3+y^2) \, dx \, dy$$

However, according to [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28integrate+%28x%5E3%2By%5E2%29+dx+from+-y%5E%282%2F3%29+to+a+%29+dy+from+-a+to+a) the above integral evaluates to $0$. The correct answer according to the textbook should be $\frac{8a^4}{3}$. Not sure where I messed up. Any insight would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Well, notice that Wolframalpha is also treating as $a=0$ in the evaluation. Meaning, since the outer integral is then $0$ to $0$, of course it will produce a zero volume.

Comment: @mathematics2x2life good point; however, if you look at the expression for the indefinite integral at the bottom, the powers of $y$ are all odd, so evaluating from $-a$ to $a$ will result in $0$.

Comment: Your integration region is actually the square $[-a,a] \times [-a,a]$. Are you supposed to use double integrals or can you use a triple? It would be easy to visualize in this case.

Comment: @Marc triple integrals are fine as well. Wouldn't you arrive at the same expression above though?

Comment: @casandra Yes. Compute the integral in the square and everything should work fine.

Comment: @Marc do you mean evaluate the following integral: $V = \int_{-a}^{a} \int_{-a}^{a} (x^3+y^2) \, dx \, dy$? That is actually what I did initially and the answer I got was $\frac{4a^4}{3}$ ([wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28integrate+%28x%5E3%2By%5E2%29+dx+from+-a+to+a+%29+dy+from+-a+to+a)) which is half the answer the textbook gives.

Comment: @casandra Don't forget your textbook is possibly wrong. Mind if I ask what textbook is it?

Comment: @Marc that is a possibility (my textbook is often wrong). It's Schaum's Outlines of Advanced Calculus 3rd Ed. But in any case, why is the integral I set up in the original problem wrong? It makes sense that the lower bound of $x$ should be $-y^{2/3}$ so as to ensure that $z$ is always positive, no?

Comment: @casandra No, it doesn't. The region of integration, which in this case is given, would be the projected region in whatever plane you decided to choose as your integration variables. Assuming you had to find the region, it would be best to set $z=0$, find this region, and then compute.

Comment: @casandra You also have another problem with your input into wolframalpha and your work. Notice that you want $x^3+y^2\geq 0 \rightarrow x^3\geq -y^2 \rightarrow x\geq (-y^2)^{1/3}$. You may know what you meant, but wolframalpha for example will not understand what you meant and there is a difference in output between $(-y^2)^{1/3}$ and $-(y^{2/3})$ (Recall that $(x^a)^b=x^{ab}$ does not always hold if $a<0$. In fact $-y^2<0$. So that is another possibility for where your issues come from.